# Having trouble with mysql variables, what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, mysql-variables

See below and test [here](https://paiza.io/projects/e/4xSIKVTkT1teRassVo625g?theme=twilight).
I've been pulling my hair out over this for a couple of hours now. I've searched many posts and as best I can tell everything is correct.
I'm having trouble with the IF comparison and the @malefemale variable. 
I can pull this off by declaring variables in a stored procedure without any problems, I just want to get the damn thing working in the online editor above to share with a friend, and in this case, just to get the damn thing working at all. What am I missing?

```
create table test(id int, gender varchar(10), salary int);
insert into test(id, gender, salary) values (1, 'male', 40000), (2, 'male', 50000),  (3,'male', 40000), (4, 'female', 60000), (5, 'female', 60000), (6,'female', 40000);

set @m =0;
set @f =0;
set @malefemale = 'same';

select count(*) into @m from test WHERE gender like 'male' and salary >= 50000;
select count(*) into @f from test WHERE gender like 'female' and salary >= 50000;

if @m > @f then
    @malefemale = 'male';
else if @f > @m then
    set @malefemale ='female';
endif

select @malefemale;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are utterly unnecessary for this query:

```
select (case sign(sum(gender = 'male') - sum(gender = 'female') )
             when 1 then 'male'
             when -1 then 'female'
             when 0 then 'same'
        end)
from test 
where gender like 'male' ;
```

If you are running this as MySQL code, then your problem is probably not the variables, but the `if`.  It is only allowed in programming blocks -- think stored procedures, functions, and triggers.

Answer (score 1):

According to the mysql documentation if statements are only allowed in stored programs.

> The IF statement for stored programs implements a basic conditional construct.

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html)

However. There is an IF you could use.

```
create table test(id int, gender varchar(10), salary int);
insert into test(id, gender, salary) values (1, 'male', 40000), (2, 'male', 50000),  
(3,'male', 40000), (4, 'female', 60000), (5, 'female', 60000), (6,'female', 40000);

set @m =0;
set @f =0;

select count(*) into @m from test WHERE gender like 'male' and salary >= 50000;
select count(*) into @f from test WHERE gender like 'female' and salary >= 50000;


select if (@m > @f, 'male', 'female')
```

For explanation:
select if ([CONDITION], [THEN], [ELSE])

And because I can't comment your question. The downvote may be because of your unnecessary swearing. I can understand that you're frustrated but maybe one "damn" would be enough.

Comment: Thanks, and noted about my frustration.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Gordon Linoff' response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52569044/10421809) but, as I can not comment yet, I would just like to correct two things in the code:

```
select (case sign(sum(gender = 'male') - sum(gender = 'female') )
             when 1 then 'male' 
             when -1 then 'female'
             when 0 then 'same'
        end)
from test;
```

The condition was added for when the amount of gender is equal (same), which is also an expected response. The condition `where gender like 'male'` was removed, that was limiting the search to only the gender 'male'.